# mySQL Data Provider .NET Core 2.0

Tags: mysql, aspnetboilerplate

Looking for help for some solutions on switching out the default data provider for the project from MS SQL to mySQL. Eventually with the intent of deploying the solution to Auruora on AWS.

After installing the nuget package I get something along the lines of :

`System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Clone' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.MySQLOptionsExtension' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=6.10.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.`

This lead me to believe that there is no .NET 2.0 Entity Framework Core extention that runs for MySQL. Do I have to rollback to a different version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **EntityFrameworkCore**, it's suggested to use **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql**.
You may refer to their [Getting Started documentation](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#getting-started).

A fellow member of the community has kindly summarised the essential steps [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2710#issuecomment-347381377):

> 1. Put Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql into the xxx.EntityFrameworkCore project's .csproj file (see step 2 in the Pomelo getting started guide)
> 2. In your xxxDbContextConfigurer class put `builder.UseMySql(...)` rather than `builder.UseSqlServer(...)`
> 3. Change the connection string found in the appsettings.json file in the xxx.Web.Host project